# Getting Response in ContainerResponseFilter's (JAX-RS 2)

Tags: java, jax-ws, jax-rs, cors

I am trying to port [this CORS filter](https://raw.github.com/ysangkok/jax-rs-ng-todo/master/topack/WEB-INF/classes/our_package/ResponseCorsFilter.java) to JAX-RS 2.

However, I do not see how to get the [Response](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) object (as in the old code) from the [ContainerResponseContext](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html) I get passed in the overridden method of [ContainerResponseFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html).

If there is a more elegant way to do CORS with JAX-RS 2, that would be preferrable of course. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thre response is directly accessible **as** the `ContainerResponseContext`:

```
@Provider
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
            ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
           responseContext.getHeaders()
                .putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
           responseContext.getHeaders()
                 .putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                     "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
           List<String> reqHead=requestContext.getHeaders()
                     .get("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
           if(null != reqHead){
                responseContext.getHeaders()
                   .put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
                        new ArrayList<Object>(reqHead));
           }
    }

}
```

Comment: But using this how can i get My response BODY ?

Comment: There is the `ContainerResponseContext.setEntity` method which allows to substitute the entire entity.

Comment: Thanks...
can i do reverse operation on `ContainerRequestContext` ?
I mean i want to get POJO from `ContainerRequestContext` in filter .
from `ContainerRequestContext`, we can get `EntityStream` from that,but i want `Entity` as we get in ``ContainerResponseContext``

Comment: There is `ContainerResponseContext.getEntity()`, according to the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html) it does what you need.

Comment: yes, `ContainerResponseContext.getEntity()` but same method or behavior i need in  `ContainerRequestContext` 
Is there any way to get `Entity object` from `ContainerRequestContext`

Comment: There is no way to obtain the object using this type of filter, because it is binded to the outer level of the request/response cycle. What you need may be obtained implementing a [ReaderInterceptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html), and using the method `proceed()` of the [ReaderInterceptorContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptorContext.html), passed to `aroundReadFrom`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51361/discussion-between-carlo-pellegrini-and-ankit337)