# Overriding all JAX-RS responses with a constant response header

Tags: jax-rs

I'm writing a fairly generic webapp that I want to be JAX-RS "pure", though I'm developing using Jetty and CXF.  I want to do something extremely simple, I want for ALL HTTP responses a header added (not just for the methods I'm writing code for, even auto-handled 415 responses).

Solutions for [How do i modify HTTP headers for a JAX-WS response in CXF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736709/how-do-i-modify-http-headers-for-a-jax-ws-response-in-cxf) seem overly complex (and specific for CXF's implementations of JAX-RS)for just needing to add:
  MyServerVersion : 1.0
to every response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is with a [**`ContainerResponseFilter`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html). See *Chapter 6: Filters and Interceptors* of the [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

You'll want to add your header to [**`ContainerResponseContext#getHeaders()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html#getHeaders%28%29). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880432/getting-response-in-containerresponsefilters-jax-rs-2) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer above, I summarized what I did in [a blog post](http://stevespeicher.blogspot.com/2013/08/supporting-accept-post-in-jax-rs.html) and it gives some background and context for the `Accept-Post` response header I was working with and code samples.